# Adding Categories And Post Tags Boxes For Custom Post Type In WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

hi there how do I add the category or tags on custom post type portfolio? example logo, business cards etc

This is what I currently have in my functions.php

```html
<?php
   add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');  

function portfolio_register() {  
    $args = array(  
        'label' => __('Portfolio'),  
        'singular_label' => __('Project'),  
        'public' => true,  
        'show_ui' => true,  
        'capability_type' => 'post',  
        'hierarchical' => false,  
        'rewrite' => true,  
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'categories' )  
       );  flush_rewrite_rules(); 

    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
```

and on my template.php page

```html
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => $num_posts
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

     <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>         





                        <article>
                            <div class="image fit">



                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <header>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                    <p><?php the_tags ( ', ' ); ?>.</p> 
                            </header>

                            <footer>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-success">More</a>
                            </footer>
                        </article>





                 <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Please advise me the best solution. Thank you in advance

Comment: look into register_taxonomy

Comment: hi there, where do I apply that?